# Why can't we get access from the inner's class constructor to another inner class?

Tags: java, class

```
class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
    }

    public class SuperInner{
        int a;
    }

    public class Inner{
        public class MegaInner{
            public MegaInner(){
                Main.SuperInner.this.a = 6; //error: not an enclosing class: Main.SuperInner
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**[IDEON](http://ideone.com/cR7rIC)**

What **[JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.4)** says is:

> Let C be the class denoted by ClassName. Let n be an integer such that
>   C is the n'th lexically enclosing class of the class in which the
>   qualified this expression appears.
>
> [...]
>
> It is a compile-time error if the current class is not an inner class
>   of class C or C itself.

In the case `C:=Main`, the set of inner classes `S := {SuperInner, MegaInner, Inner}`. Which means the code above should work fine. What's wrong?

Comment: Try `Main.Inner.this.a`, which should give an *unknown field `a`* error, which makes sense since `MegaInner` does not extend `SuperInner` (so it doesn't inherit the field).  `Main.SuperInner.this` wont work cause `MegaInner` is not inside `SuperInner`, its inside `Inner` which also isnt in `SuperInner`

Answer (score 1):

One could have multiple instances of `SuperInner`, as well as of `Inner` or `MegaInner`.
Calling `Main.SupperInner.this.a` from within `MegaInner`, it wouldn't be clear which instance (if there is an instance at all) should have the `a` variable set to 6.

The inner classes behave much like normal classes: one always needs an instance to set a variable in them. `Main.SuperInner.this` does not denote an instance from `MegaInner`'s view, as `this` only refers to the class-hierarchy of `MegaInner`, which `SuperInner` is not a part of.

Answer (score 1):

The "Qualified this" expression `Main.SuperInner.this.a` appers inside `MegaInner`.

The enclosing classes of `MegaInner` are `Inner` and `Main`. So `this` is the 0th qualified `this`, `Inner.this` is the 1st qualified this, and `Main.this` is the 2nd qualified this.

The part you were missing is that it has to be **an enclosing class** of the class where the expression with the `this` appears. `SuperInner` is not an enclosing class of `MegaInner` and therefore the `Qualified this` does not apply to it.

Think about it in reality. A `this` expression refers to an *instance* of the class. It does not refer to the class itself. You cannot refer to `this` from a static method, for example.

Now, when you create an instance of `MegaInner`, it has to be part of an actual instance of `Inner` and an actual instance of `Main`. But there is no guarantee that there is an actual instance of `SuperInner`. The code of the enclosing classes may create objects of type `SuperInner` at any time and independently of instances of `Inner`.

Thus, you can't access a `this` of it at compile time. But if you are given an instance of it through a reference variable, you are allowed to access the variable `a`, as they are all members of the same outer class.